# Как сделать выпадающим список тегов при клике

Tags: wordpress, список, теги, виджет

Есть виджет списка тегов в сайдбаре в WP открытый по умолчанию. Прикрутил ниже красивое облако тегов, но хочется оставить возможность, чтобы при клике выпадал весь список тегов, как сейчас на скриншоте, а сам виджет показывал только слово "теги" и ниже выпадающий список с описанием "весь список".

[image: скрин виджета сейчас]

Пытался оформить через `<select>`, но увы.
Вот сам код виджета:

```
<?php
/**
 * Widget API: WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud class
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Widgets
 * @since 4.4.0
 */

/**
 * Core class used to implement a Tag cloud widget.
 *
 * @since 2.8.0
 *
 * @see WP_Widget
 */
class WP_Widget_Tag_Cloud extends WP_Widget {

    /**
     * Sets up a new Tag Cloud widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     */
    public function __construct() {
        $widget_ops = array( 'description' => __( "A cloud of your most used tags.") );
        parent::__construct('tag_cloud', __('Tag Cloud'), $widget_ops);
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the content for the current Tag Cloud widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $args     Display arguments including 'before_title', 'after_title',
     *                        'before_widget', and 'after_widget'.
     * @param array $instance Settings for the current Tag Cloud widget instance.
     */

    public function widget( $args, $instance ) {
        $current_taxonomy = $this->_get_current_taxonomy($instance);
        if ( !empty($instance['title']) ) {
            $title = $instance['title'];
        } else {
            if ( 'post_tag' == $current_taxonomy ) {
                $title = __('Tags');
            } else {
                $tax = get_taxonomy($current_taxonomy);
                $title = $tax->labels->name;
            }
        }

        /**
         * Filter the taxonomy used in the Tag Cloud widget.
         *
         * @since 2.8.0
         * @since 3.0.0 Added taxonomy drop-down.
         *
         * @see wp_tag_cloud()
         *
         * @param array $current_taxonomy The taxonomy to use in the tag cloud. Default 'tags'.
         */
        $tag_cloud = wp_tag_cloud( apply_filters( 'widget_tag_cloud_args', array(
            'taxonomy' => $current_taxonomy,
            'echo' => false
        ) ) );

        if ( empty( $tag_cloud ) ) {
            return;
        }

        /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/widgets/class-wp-widget-pages.php */
        $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', $title, $instance, $this->id_base );

        echo $args['before_widget'];
        if ( $title ) {
            echo $args['before_title'] . $title . $args['after_title'];
        }

        echo '<div class="tagcloud">';

        echo $tag_cloud;

        echo "</div>\n";
        echo $args['after_widget'];
    }

    /**
     * Handles updating settings for the current Tag Cloud widget instance.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $new_instance New settings for this instance as input by the user via
     *                            WP_Widget::form().
     * @param array $old_instance Old settings for this instance.
     * @return array Settings to save or bool false to cancel saving.
     */
    public function update( $new_instance, $old_instance ) {
        $instance = array();
        $instance['title'] = sanitize_text_field( stripslashes( $new_instance['title'] ) );
        $instance['taxonomy'] = stripslashes($new_instance['taxonomy']);
        return $instance;
    }

    /**
     * Outputs the Tag Cloud widget settings form.
     *
     * @since 2.8.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $instance Current settings.
     */
    public function form( $instance ) {
        $current_taxonomy = $this->_get_current_taxonomy($instance);
        $title_id = $this->get_field_id( 'title' );
        $instance['title'] = ! empty( $instance['title'] ) ? esc_attr( $instance['title'] ) : '';

        echo '<p><label for="' . $title_id .'">' . __( 'Title:' ) . '</label>
            <input type="text" class="widefat" id="' . $title_id .'" name="' . $this->get_field_name( 'title' ) .'" value="' . $instance['title'] .'" />
        </p>';

        $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( array( 'show_tagcloud' => true ), 'object' );
        $id = $this->get_field_id( 'taxonomy' );
        $name = $this->get_field_name( 'taxonomy' );
        $input = '<input type="hidden" id="' . $id . '" name="' . $name . '" value="%s" />';

        switch ( count( $taxonomies ) ) {

        // No tag cloud supporting taxonomies found, display error message
        case 0:
            echo '<p>' . __( 'The tag cloud will not be displayed since there are no taxonomies that support the tag cloud widget.' ) . '</p>';
            printf( $input, '' );
            break;

        // Just a single tag cloud supporting taxonomy found, no need to display options
        case 1:
            $keys = array_keys( $taxonomies );
            $taxonomy = reset( $keys );
            printf( $input, esc_attr( $taxonomy ) );
            break;

        // More than one tag cloud supporting taxonomy found, display options
        default:
            printf(
                '<p><label for="%1$s">%2$s</label>' .
                '<select class="widefat" id="%1$s" name="%3$s">',
                $id,
                __( 'Taxonomy:' ),
                $name
            );

            foreach ( $taxonomies as $taxonomy => $tax ) {
                printf(
                    '<option value="%s"%s>%s</option>',
                    esc_attr( $taxonomy ),
                    selected( $taxonomy, $current_taxonomy, false ),
                    $tax->labels->name
                );
            }

            echo '</select></p>';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the taxonomy for the current Tag cloud widget instance.
     *
     * @since 4.4.0
     * @access public
     *
     * @param array $instance Current settings.
     * @return string Name of the current taxonomy if set, otherwise 'post_tag'.
     */
    public function _get_current_taxonomy($instance) {
        if ( !empty($instance['taxonomy']) && taxonomy_exists($instance['taxonomy']) )
            return $instance['taxonomy'];

        return 'post_tag';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте через JS: выставить высоту виджета равной высоте надписи "Теги" в CSS, а на сам контейнер содержий "Теги" повесить обработчик клика который будет раскрывать этот виджет на полную высоту

Comment: спасибо за подсказку! только никак не могу вклинить корректно в код виджета ничего, сразу ошибки.

Comment: Ну у вас же в теме есть какой-нибудь js файл. Вот в него и добавьте. Не забудьте навесить код на событие DOMContentLoad.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос разрешен. Ответ нашел здесь: http://polezniy.com/2011/02/17/vyvodim-oblako-tegov-v-vide-vypadayushhego-spiska/ (если кому-то еще будет полезно).
Благодарю за комментарии, сильно помогли в поисках!